# Embedding javascript in <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I have following code

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
                            {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
                                    <tr class="template-download fade <?php if ($userExpired) echo 'restricted' ?> " search-name="{%=file.name%}" search-id="{%=file.id%}">
                                    {% if (file.error) { %}
                                            <td class="name">
                                                    <span class="delete"><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="nomargin"></span>
                                                    <span >{%=file.name%}</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="size right"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                                            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
                                    {% } else { %}
                                            <td class="name">
                                                    <span class="delete"><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="nomargin"></span>

                                                    {% if (file.status_code == 2 || file.status_code == 3) { %}                                                             




                                                  <span class="clickcursor filename <?php if ($userExpired) echo 'restricted' ?> "  title="Click here to Analyze" data-file="{%=file.name%}" data-target="[tracefile]" data-id="{%=file.id%}" data-idtarget="[trace_id]" data-formid="dashboard">
                                                            {%=file.name%}
```

I want to add a javascript code that whenever  {%=file.name%}  is clicked

```
<script type='text/javascript'>


$.blockUI.defaults.message="<h5><img src='../ajax-loader.gif'/>&nbsp;Loading...</h5>";

    $(document).ready(function(){
            set_trace_links();
    });
    function set_trace_links(){
    $.click (
    function(){
            $.blockUI();
    });
    } 
</script>
```

is called.

Please reply .

Comment: My reply: you do not show any effort for your question. You just dump your code without proper formatting and ask us to fix it (not even telling the actual error/problem is).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse that template into your HTML and add click events.

There are two ways to do this, you can either delegate them from the parent element or add them to your element directly.

Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but I think its best to add a class to your span and do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('span.fileName').on('click', $.blockUI);
});
```

If you are rendering this template a lot its better to delegate it from the parent, from jQuery 1.7+ you can use this syntax:

```
var parentSelector = ''; // YOUR PARENT SELECTOR HERE
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(parentSelector || document).on('click', 'span.fileName', $.blockUI);
});
```

If you are using older versions of jQuery, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('span.fileName').live('click', $.blockUI);
});
```

Delegating simply means binding the handler on the parent to listen for events on specific children.

Also, to make sure the $ sign actually means "jQuery", It is a good practice to put your inline script code in an IIFE

So the first example would look like this:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('span.fileName').on('click', $.blockUI);
  });
})(jQuery);
```